# Getting the literal value of a variable without echo

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function below, list_child_sibling_pages, which returns a string of 'hidden' when the initial 2 if / ifelse statements are false.

I need to put the literal return value 'hidden' in to the array below as shown here

array( 'classname' => 'custom child-parent-menu-container '. $hidden, 'description' => 'Automatically add a child page menu to parent pages. Automatically add a sibling menu to child pages' );

I know I can output it with with

echo list_child_sibling_pages();

But I don't know how I would work that in to the code below. The value is returned fine if I just echo it out on it's own my only issue is echoing it where I need it

Relevant code follows

function tmm_child_parent_menu() {

```
function list_child_sibling_pages()
{   
global $post;// if outside the loop
$post_type = '&post_type='.get_post_type(); 
$children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.$post_type);
$parent_title = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
$parent_permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
 
//child pages   
    if ( $post->post_parent && !is_search() && !is_404() ) 
    { ?> 
            <h4><?php echo '<a href="'.$parent_permalink.'">'.$parent_title.'</a>'; ?></h4>
            <ul class="parent-page-children">
            <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&sort_column=menu_order'.$post_type ); ?>
            </ul>
        <?php 
    } 

//parent pages
    elseif ( count( $children ) != 0 && !is_search() && !is_404() )
    { ?>
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <ul class="parent-page-children">
            <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order'.$post_type ); ?>
            </ul>
        <?php 
    } 
    else 
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }
}   

    $hidden = list_child_sibling_pages();
    /* Widget settings. */
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'custom child-parent-menu-container '. $hidden, 'description' => 'Automatically add a child page menu to parent pages. Automatically add a sibling menu to child pages' );
```

Answer (score 0):

confused but i think you want

```
        $array=array('classname'=>'custom child-parent-menu-container '.list_child_sibling_pages(),
'description'=>'Automatically add a child page menu to parent pages. Automatically add a sibling menu to child pages');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have actually tried that 

$widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'custom child-parent-menu-container '.list_child_sibling_pages(), 'description' => 'Automatically add a child page menu to parent pages. Automatically add a sibling menu to child pages' );

but that doesn't seem to return anything for me. In the list of classes in the html nothing is added.